# Postgres: How to change array delimiter to something other than ',' & trigger before copy arrays?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm building a database for chemical names. My main table contains two attributes, something like this:

```
         CREATE TABLE chemicals 
         (
             chemical id            int PRIMARY KEY,
             names                  varchar(200)[]
         );
```

The table is then filled with COPY

```
         COPY chemicals FROM chemicals_file delimiters E'\t';
```

I have formated the chemicals_file like this:

```
         chemical_id     { name1  name2 name3 }
         ......................................
```

As you know chemical names (IUPAC names) contain the character ',' inside, so I cannot use it as a delimiter for the array of names. I can't find on the online documentation any way to specify another delimiter for the array. Could you please help me?

Another option I would have here, since the original chemicals file has one entry per name, like:

```
         chemical_id_1    name1
         chemical_id_1    name2
         .......................
         chemical_id_6    name3
         .......................
```

would be to create a trigger BEFORE COPY (can this be done?) so that if the chemical_id exits in the table the name is added into the existing array of names, instead of creating a whole new row, but I don't know how these could be specified.

I have created already a trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE but it doesn't seem to work for COPY

Thanks a lot for the help ;)

Comment: Please don't put lots of caps in your titles.

Comment: it will for a IUPAC name like this: (2-(2',6'-dimethoxy)phenoxyethylamino)methylbenzo-1,4-dioxane  That's a unique name. According to default delimiter for the array on isertion it would split this name into 3 names, on each comma, thus the entry would not be correct

Answer (score 2):

Try text format like this:

```
chemical_id_1   { "one,two,three", "four", "five,six" }
...
```

Comment: It should work. Your problem lays somewhere else. Maybe in COPY options? There is no option "delimiters". Should be "delimiter". I tried simple text file with tab characters and COPY without any options with success. Or maybe some of names are longer then 200 chars? (My table has field "name" of type "text[]").

Comment: +1. It should work. Please provide error messages and the exact line that fails

Comment: Exactly. FYI, the delimiter of array items is given by the array's element type, as specified in the section 8.15.2 or 8.15.6 of the PostgreSQL documentation. Handling of values which themselves contain the delimiter is described there, too.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly you want a multivalued column, but that is evil. I'd use this:

```
chemical(id, name)
chemical_name(id, chemical_id, name)
```

And in chemical you have a handy preferred name to use in JOINs